# ASP.net Modal Pop up extender and DropDownlist autopostback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a `GridView` control where if the user click on the auto-generated edit button. A window will pop up using modal pop-up extender with a drop down list for user to select. The problem is the `SelectedIndexChanged` event will not fire if `AutoPostBack` is set to false.

But if I set the `AutoPostBack` to true the pop-up will go away without firing the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Is it possible to have a control with `AutoPostBack` set to true inside the modal pop-up?

Comment: you might want to tag this as ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

Please put below code on drop down server side change event

modalpopup.show();
updatepanel.update();

where modalpopup is "ID" of modalpopupextender
and updatepanel is  "ID" of updatepanel

Comment: It is not proper to ask people to 'accept' or 'vote' for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the selectedindexchange
>   event will not fire if autopostback is
>   set to false...

I'm not sure that statement is strictly true. Isn't it a case that if autopostback is false, the SelectedIndexChange event fires during the next postback? So if you change the index, then click a Submit button, that's when the index change event is fired.

This isn't much good if you need server code to run to respond to the index change while the popup is still showing, but otherwise, you can still respond to the index change.

If you need to change something in the popup in response to the index change, you can always use client-side javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UpdatePanel` to resolve this problem.  Wrap the `DropDownList` and any other controls that might give similar issue inside of an `UpdatePanel`, inside of the pop-up control.  This will allow the pop-up to continue showing, while executing your postback code at the right time.